# How to make video thumbnail in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a flutter app that shows the list of video files from internal storage...***now I want to display thumbnails of videos in video list so how can I do this in my flutter app?*** If anyone have any Idea then please help me.

I am using ListBuilder widget.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For Others. Use [video player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin as thumbnail. It's very efficient compared to those libraries and also works for iOS. Just create StatefulWidget as like item (if you want to show in list use that widget as item). See below example.

```
class _VideoItemState extends State<VideoItem> {
VideoPlayerController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.video.file.path)
  ..initialize().then((_) {
    setState(() {});  //when your thumbnail will show.
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
_controller.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListTile(
  leading: _controller.value.initialized
      ? Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 56.0,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        )
      : CircularProgressIndicator(),
  title: Text(widget.video.file.path.split('/').last),
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            VideoPlayerPage(videoUrl: widget.video.file.path),
      ),
    );
  },
);
 }
}
```

Comment: I think it will show the thumbnail of single video, what about the list of video urls

Comment: The circle loading loads forever for me. I get this in my log => E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16007): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16007):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error,

Comment: how to get video from json list??

Comment: It should be _controller.value.isInitialized

Comment: It is not working it is giving the same error as Kamrul Hasan Jony wrote in his comment.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) plugin too, like so:

For a video file:

```
final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
  video: videofile.path,
  imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
  maxWidth: 128, // specify the width of the thumbnail, let the height auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
  quality: 25,
);
```

OR from a video URL:

```
final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
  video: "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4",
  thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
  imageFormat: ImageFormat.WEBP,
  maxHeight: 64, // specify the height of the thumbnail, let the width auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
  quality: 75,
);
```

Comment: How to take VideoThumbnail .avi format video

Answer (score 3):

i crafted this by [@Hussnain Haidar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093984/19130814).

```
class VideoThumbnail extends StatefulWidget {
  String videoPath;
  VideoThumbnail(this.videoPath);

  @override
  State<VideoThumbnail> createState() => _VideoThumbnailState();
}

class _VideoThumbnailState extends State<VideoThumbnail> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoPath)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {}); //when your thumbnail will show.
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: InkWell(
        child: _controller.value.isInitialized
            ? Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 56.0,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => VideoViewer(widget.videoPath), //VideoViewer
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, works on first try, thx!, i just do'nt know if this a good practice to put in a list if all items are a complet video pleyer.

Answer (score 2):

I used below code. Using **video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3**

```
  final thumbnailPath = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
        video: aFile.path,
        imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
        timeMs: 1,
        quality: 50);
```

Make sure you store in application Document Directory. Specially for **ios** while saving the video file.

```
final Directory _appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the plugin [thumbnails](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/thumbnails) `https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/thumbnails`
2. Create a folder to store all thumbnails in phone storage.
3. Add this code in one function,
   code:

   ```
    String thumb = await Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
    thumbnailFolder: folderPath,
    videoFile: videoPathUrl,
    imageType: ThumbFormat.PNG,//this image will store in created folderpath
    quality: 30);
   ```
4. Now show that image in one container and `onTap` of that `container/widget` pass URL of video to `open/play` video.

Comment: Is there any similar solution available which support iOS also

Comment: the solution doesn't work on iOS , maybe because it is created with swift 3 and newer (Xcode 10 for example) doesn't support it .

Comment: there is another plugin called video_thumnail but for me that did not worked app crashes but this one works on android i am not sure about ios

Comment: this plugin is discontinued now

Answer (score 0):

I used below code. Using video_compress: ^3.1.2

```
 void getVideoThumbnail(String file) async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    String newPath = path.join(appDocPath,'${getRandomString(10)}.mp4');
    File filepath = await File(file).copy(newPath);
final thumbnailFile =
          await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(filepath.path, quality: 50);
}
```

ThumbnailQuality Range:- 1-100

For Generating Random Name use below code:

```
String getRandomString(int length) => String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
      length, (_) => _chars.codeUnitAt(_rnd.nextInt(_chars.length))));
```