# how to create a thumbnail of a vedio after getting vedio file path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test

I want to show the thumbnail of the video in lisviewbuilder here is the path of a video after getting from device storage.

```
files[index]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make video thumbnail in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838120/how-to-make-video-thumbnail-in-flutter)

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: @FaizanAbbasBangash now you're question is focusing on more than one issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) package to generate a thumbnail for your video file, and it's implementation would be like this :

```
 final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
  video: files[index}, // video path
  imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
  maxWidth: 128, // specify the width of the thumbnail, let the height auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
  quality: 25,
);
```

you can try implementing it like this, first add this method in your class:

```
Future<Uint8List?> _thumbnailImage(path) async {
  return await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
    video: path, // video path
    imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
    maxWidth:
        128, // specify the width of the thumbnail, let the height auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
    quality: 25,
  );
}
```

then use this `FutureBuilder` to show it:

```
 FutureBuilder<Uint8List?>(
          future: _thumbnailImage(files[index]),
          builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<Uint8List?> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
            }
            return Text("error");
          },
        ),
```

You can also use it with combination with the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker), to get the video path from the device like this:

```
  final XFile? image =
  await ImagePicker().pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  final String pathToUse = image!.path;
```

then use that path in the `_thumbnailImage()` method.

Comment: how can i use this code inside lisview leading

Comment: can you plz edit. path of my vedio is files[index]

Comment: I made a change for it based on your path files[index]

Comment: how can i use this code in leading..?

Comment: since it's asynchronous, you will need a FutureBuilder to manage it, when it got the full uint8list of the thumbnail from that Future, you can show it as an image with Image.memory(uint8list)

Comment: can you please edit code

Comment: Duplicate answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333598/5882307

Comment: I added the implementation of it with FutureBuilder, you can try it

Comment: @OMi Shah or maybe I used the code given for use from the official package page ? https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail

Comment: @Gwhyyy, obviously possible. But there's no point in adding duplicate answers, atleast answers without a change. Mark duplicate questions and close. :)

Comment: it shows The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Uint8List>?'

Comment: I aim to give help. not to run searching for duplication questions + the other question don't give example on implementing its widget

Comment: my mistake, wait

Comment: I added type, give it another try

Comment: future: _thumbnailImage(files[index]),  this line shows...The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Uint8List>?

Comment: return error......!

Comment: I specified type in my sample, can share with me a gist of the code you used

Comment: and are you sure that the files[index] is a valid path ?

Comment: this is the output when i print files[index]

Comment: @Gwhyyy, your ORIGINAL answer was exact duplicate answer for which I said. Now you have edited and added further details which is good :)

Comment: output /storage/emulated/0/.mp4

Comment: also, this question focuses on multiple issues which should be closed, if I am not wrong :)

Comment: it works after clearing my cache thnks